# sqlplus exit on unhandled exception

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is there a way in sqlplus to exit with an error code when there is an unhandled exception, but not if exception is caught and handled?
I can add `whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;` but this exits even if the error is handled.

Typically, if I add the `whenever ...` in the below script, it will exit immediately, even though the exception is caught and "handled" (sort of).

```
BEGIN
 -- faulty statement
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from missing_table';
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
/
-- Other statements
```

Comment: Firstly, writing a plain `select * from missing_table;` is wrong as an `INTO` clause is expected inside PL/SQL. Even if the error was "missing table", The **compilation** of the block fails and hence it won't run the block.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Ok, this is just for the example. I updated the example with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - but do you still have the issue when you use `execute immediate`?

Comment: @AlexPoole It actually works as I wanted. Sorry for bothering. I must have been too tired when I tried it yesterday evening.